# How to read file in pandas with unfix whitespace/s separation?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a *textfile* that contains 2 columns of data. They are separated with unfix number of whitespace/s. I want to load it on a *pandas* DataFrame.

Example:

```
   306.000000     1.125783
   307.000000     0.008101
   308.000000    -0.005917
   309.000000     0.003784
   310.000000    -0.516513
```

Please note that it also starts with whitespace/s.

My desired output would be like:

```
output = {'Wavelength': [306.000000, 307.000000, 308.000000, 309.000000, 310.000000],
          'Reflectance': [1.125783, 0.008101, -0.005917, 0.003784, -0.516513]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=output)
```

Comment: don you want keep initials blanks?

Comment: Nope. I don't want to.

Comment: It does not contain whitespace/s. There's an answer below which solved my problem.

Comment: The post does not solve my problem with whitespace/s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\\s+', names=['Wavelength', 'Reflectance'], header=None)
```

Comment: There's no `columns` argument.

Comment: Sorry I got it confused with another pandas function. Replace `columns` with `names`